Why only AppleClang cannot compile this code and gives "deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined"?
I'm trying to write a cross-platform library which uses std::visit and recursive lambdas, but it failed to compile only on macOS. The erroneous part minimizes to the following code:
// test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

using namespace std;

template <typename... Ts>
struct Overloaded : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator()...;
};

template <typename Fn>
struct YCombinator {
    Fn fn;
    explicit YCombinator(Fn &&fn) : fn(std::forward<Fn>(fn)) {}
    template <typename... Args>
    inline decltype(auto) operator()(Args &&...args) const {
        return fn(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

// Deduction guide, not needed if using C++20
template <typename Fn>
YCombinator(Fn &&fn) -> YCombinator<Fn>;

int main(void) {
    auto visitor = YCombinator(Overloaded{
        [&](const auto &v, const int &i) -> void {
            if (i) {
                cout << "i: " << i << endl;
                variant<char, int> b{char(i - 1)};
                visit(v, b);
            }
        },
        [&](const auto &v, const char &c) -> void {
            if (c) {
                cout << "c: " << int(c) << endl;
                variant<char, int> b{int(c) - 1};
                visit(v, b);
            }
        },
    });
    variant<char, int> a{char(10)};
    visit(visitor, a);
    return 0;
}

I tested the above code in the following environments:

Linux

GCC 14.2.1: g++ -std=c++20 test.cpp
Clang 18.1.8: clang++ -std=c++20 test.cpp


Windows

VS 2022 with MSVC 14.40: cl.exe /EHsc /std:c++20 test.cpp
Clang 19.1.0: clang++.exe -std=c++20 test.cpp



All of them compile and run successfully. But under macOS, AppleClang 16.0.0 and clang 18.1 (installed via homebrew llvm) gives the following error:
test.cpp:31:17: error: function 'visit<const YCombinator<Overloaded<(lambda at test.cpp:27:9), (lambda at test.cpp:34:9)>> &, std::variant<char, int> &, void>' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
   31 |                 visit(v, b);
      |                 ^
test.cpp:17:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'main()::(anonymous class)::operator()<YCombinator<Overloaded<(lambda at test.cpp:27:9), (lambda at test.cpp:34:9)>>>' requested here
   17 |         return fn(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      |                ^
/usr/local/opt/llvm@18/bin/../include/c++/v1/__type_traits/invoke.h:341:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'YCombinator<Overloaded<(lambda at test.cpp:27:9), (lambda at test.cpp:34:9)>>::operator()<int &>' requested here
  341 | decltype(std::declval<_Fp>()(std::declval<_Args>()...))
      |          ^
/usr/local/opt/llvm@18/bin/../include/c++/v1/__type_traits/invoke.h:351:19: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template '__invoke' [with _Fp = const YCombinator<Overloaded<(lambda at test.cpp:27:9), (lambda at test.cpp:34:9)>> &, _Args = <int &>]
  351 |   static decltype(std::__invoke(std::declval<_XFp>(), std::declval<_XArgs>()...)) __try_call(int);
      |                   ^
/usr/local/opt/llvm@18/bin/../include/c++/v1/__type_traits/invoke.h:357:28: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template '__try_call' [with _XFp = const YCombinator<Overloaded<(lambda at test.cpp:27:9), (lambda at test.cpp:34:9)>> &, _XArgs =(no value)]
  357 |   using _Result = decltype(__try_call<_Fp, _Args...>(0));
      |                            ^
/usr/local/opt/llvm@18/bin/../include/c++/v1/__type_traits/invoke.h:428:68: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__invokable_r<void, const YCombinator<Overloaded<(lambda at test.cpp:27:9), (lambda at test.cpp:34:9)>> &, int &>' requested here
  428 | struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_invocable : integral_constant<bool, __invokable<_Fn, _Args...>::value> {};
      |                                                                    ^
/usr/local/opt/llvm@18/bin/../include/c++/v1/__type_traits/invoke.h:434:40: note: (skipping 28 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
  434 | inline constexpr bool is_invocable_v = is_invocable<_Fn, _Args...>::value;
      |                                        ^
/usr/local/opt/llvm@18/bin/../include/c++/v1/variant:500:32: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__variant_detail::__visitation::__base::__make_fmatrix<std::__variant_detail::__visitation::__variant::__value_visitor<YCombinator<Overloaded<(lambda at test.cpp:27:9), (lambda at test.cpp:34:9)>> &> &&, std::__variant_detail::__base<std::__variant_detail::_Trait::_TriviallyAvailable, char, int> &>' requested here
  500 |     constexpr auto __fmatrix = __make_fmatrix<_Visitor&&, decltype(std::forward<_Vs>(__vs).__as_base())...>();
      |                                ^
/usr/local/opt/llvm@18/bin/../include/c++/v1/variant:586:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__variant_detail::__visitation::__base::__visit_alt<std::__variant_detail::__visitation::__variant::__value_visitor<YCombinator<Overloaded<(lambdaat test.cpp:27:9), (lambda at test.cpp:34:9)>> &>, std::__variant_detail::__impl<char, int> &>' requested here
  586 |     return __base::__visit_alt(
      |                    ^
/usr/local/opt/llvm@18/bin/../include/c++/v1/variant:598:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__variant_detail::__visitation::__variant::__visit_alt<std::__variant_detail::__visitation::__variant::__value_visitor<YCombinator<Overloaded<(lambda at test.cpp:27:9), (lambda at test.cpp:34:9)>> &>, std::variant<char, int> &>' requested here
  598 |     return __visit_alt(__make_value_visitor(std::forward<_Visitor>(__visitor)), std::forward<_Vs>(__vs)...);
      |            ^
/usr/local/opt/llvm@18/bin/../include/c++/v1/variant:1561:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__variant_detail::__visitation::__variant::__visit_value<YCombinator<Overloaded<(lambda at test.cpp:27:9), (lambda at test.cpp:34:9)>> &, std::variant<char, int> &>' requested here
 1561 |   return __variant::__visit_value(std::forward<_Visitor>(__visitor), std::forward<_Vs>(__vs)...);
      |                     ^
test.cpp:43:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::visit<YCombinator<Overloaded<(lambda at test.cpp:27:9), (lambda at test.cpp:34:9)>> &, std::variant<char, int> &, void>' requested here
   43 |     std::visit(visitor, a);
      |          ^
/usr/local/opt/llvm@18/bin/../include/c++/v1/variant:1558:1: note: 'visit<const YCombinator<Overloaded<(lambda at test.cpp:27:9), (lambda at test.cpp:34:9)>> &, std::variant<char, int> &, void>' declared here
 1558 | visit(_Visitor&& __visitor, _Vs&&... __vs) {
      | ^
1 error generated.

So why this error, and is there a way to work around it (better without drastically changing the code pattern)?

I've got different error message on clang-16: https://godbolt.org/z/E9Wdezhv1

@MarekR Yes, seems like it only compiles on clang>=17

For clang-18 via homebrew, did you follow the instructions that homebrew provided? You're likely seeing the same error because you're using the system standard library and linker, and not those that homebrew also installed.

@sweenish Yes, the full command is env LDFLAGS="-L$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/llvm@18/lib/c++ -L$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/llvm@18/lib -lunwind" /usr/local/opt/llvm@18/bin/clang++ -std=c++20 test.cpp, but still the same error.

Changing YCombinator operator to inline void operator()(Args &&...args) const fixes build issue, but this is just hiding a problem.

LLVM Clang 16 can't compile your code https://godbolt.org/z/644h634a1

@MarekR Indeed. But the wrapped function can have non-void return types.

@3CxEZiVlQ Yes. The problem is that on macos, neither can llvm clang 18/19 compiles it....

I guess clang on macOS has some issues with return type deduction currently.
Following @MarekR's findings, a workaround is to manually deduct the type with type_traits for YCombinator, i.e., replacing the YCombinator in the question with
template <typename Fn>
struct YCombinator {
    Fn fn;
    explicit YCombinator(Fn &&fn) : fn(std::forward<Fn>(fn)) {}
    template <typename... Args>
    inline invoke_result_t<Fn, YCombinator &, Args...>
    operator()(Args &&...args) const {
        return fn(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

Then the code will pass the compilation with macOS clang>=17.
